# Programmatically Loading Libraries with a Ruby REPL

Tags: ruby, read-eval-print-loop, irb

I've been trying to get load project libraries in a script, then start either IRB or ripl to allow the user to have quick interaction with project libraries. I've succeeded in doing this.

My issue is programmatically turning off command-line echo.

Manually, this is easy with a call to `irb_context.echo = false`, but this doesn't work programmatically since control is handed over to IRB at `IRB.start` and `irb_context` isn't available before the call to `IRB.start`

Answer (score 0):

If you want `IRB` to write nothing when the user gives input, you can set the info manually:

```
IRB.conf[:PROMPT][:NO_REPLY] = {
  :PROMPT_I => "%N(%m):%03n:%i> ",
  :PROMPT_S => "%N(%m):%03n:%i%l ",
  :PROMPT_C => "%N(%m):%03n:%i* ",
  :RETURN => "\n" # used to printf
}

IRB.conf[:PROMPT_MODE] = :NO_REPLY
```

This way, the return value will be ignored by the REPL, that will print just a newline. For more info, see the [official docs](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/irb/rdoc/IRB.html).

Comment: Your example doesn't work ```NoMethodError: undefined method `[]=' for :DEFAULT:Symbol```, PROMPT_MODE 
`IRB.conf[:PROMPT_MODE]` returns a symbol
`=> :DEFAULT`. Did you mean `[:PROMPT]`?

Comment: @jtzero yes, I Fixed it now

Comment: This seems to work from inside IRB, but from a script: `require 'irb'; IRB.conf[:PROMPT]` returns `nil`

Comment: @DCKlingensmithn it should, it modifies the prompt config in place

Comment: Alright, I have to initialize `IRB.conf[:PROMPT]` to empty hash to make that code snippet work, the code completes, but echo is still turned on. Here's the code I used in a script: `require 'irb';
IRB.conf[:PROMPT] = {};

IRB.conf[:PROMPT][:NO_REPLY] = {
  :PROMPT_I => "%N(%m):%03n:%i> ",
  :PROMPT_S => "%N(%m):%03n:%i%l ",
  :PROMPT_C => "%N(%m):%03n:%i* ",
  :RETURN => "\n" # used to printf
};

IRB.conf[:PROMPT_MODE] = :NO_REPLY;

IRB.start`